# check the correctness of the excel date using poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am reading the excel sheet using POI which has a date column. I want to check the correctness of the date for example if the date entered in excel is 05/45/2015. Now no month has 45 days in it. I was wondering is there any built in method available.

This didn't print **invalid date**

```
if(DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell))
{
      System.out.println("cell value-->"+cell.getDateCellValue());
}
else{
     System.out.println("invalid date");
 }
```

This code converts the date 06/45/2015 to 06/30/2015

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/YYYY");

String  s =  sdf.format(cell.getDateCellValue());
System.out.println(s);
```

I don't want such conversions.

Comment: If you type one of those invalid dates into Excel, then try to format the cell as a Number rather than a Date, what does excel show for the cell?

Answer (score 0):

You can you `SimpleDateFormat` class

```
 //String date = "05/45/2015";
 String date = DateFormatter.formatCellValue(cell);

 DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

 try {
      Date d= df.parse(date);
      //if you didnt get any exception then date is in correct format
 }catch (Exception e) {
      //date not in correct format
      return false;
 }
```

Comment: i need to pass cell.getDateCellValue() to date which is not possible since date variable is of type string. I intend to do the following if the date is of correct format: 'SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/YYYY");
String  s =  sdf.format(cell.getDateCellValue());
System.out.println(s);'

Comment: You can use DateFormatter.formatCellValue(cell) to return string value of cell.

Comment: its saying formatCellValue method is undefined for DateFormatter

Comment: which version apache poi you are using....its threre ....https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html#formatCellValue(org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell)

Answer (score 0):

This may help you. You can try [DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(Cell)](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DateUtil.html#isCellDateFormatted(org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell))- this will return a boolean telling you if the format string for the cell represents a data or not.

Comment: it gives me true even when the date is 06/45/2015 which i don't need